# How to get the camera given file names back after renaming them?

Tags: data-recovery

This may be asking for a miracle, but is there any information embedded inside an image file that contains its original camera given name? I have about 3-4000 images that I edited and renamed and want to change the name ONLY back - is such a thing possible and how would i do this? if it helps I have the original files.

Comment: Possibly… have you looked into the EXIF data of an original file?

Comment: Google "EXIF Viewer or EXIF Editor" for programs that can do this.